# Php, get the referer from an ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, http-referer

I need to get the full domain in which the user sent the ajax request to my server, and it should be somewhat secure.
The

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Returns blank.
What function should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexAmiryan, do you know any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers just don't send referrer data with XHR requests. The referer header is optional and can be forged anyway. So: *you can't*.

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is likely to give you all the protection you need (although you haven't been explicit about your usecase so it is hard to say for sure).

Comment: The ajax request does work(I have configured it via php) but it does not get the remote domain.

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is NOT a value you should trust. This value can set to whatever a user likes. In addition users can disable the referer by hand. Try to rework the script to work without a referer. However, don't RELY on the value of the referer.

Comment: @agam360 That depends on your script. IF you want to check if a request comes from a certain host then you can add the host as a param to your ajax request. Doing that the user is still able to edit this value but that is a general problem with any user sent value and can only be softened by value checks. The difference to using the http-referrer: that referrer can be disabled by user tools/plugins for anonymization without the users knowledge. He can't use your script anymore. Using the host as a param ensures that every user (without editing the value) will get at least a correct response.

Comment: @TRD Ok, I think that I came up with something, tell me if it's good. I'll create a temp-api-key: the server after each request will send a new js file as the client-side communication file, which will only change the api parameter in the object there, that key will be then check each time and generated again after lets say 10 requests, therefore no one could possibly "hack" the system, what do you think?

Comment: What is stopping the attacker requesting the new JS file with the new key every 10 requests?

Comment: @agam360 I think you should clarify what you intend to do with the api-key or with the referer. If you generate a new js-file with a different api-key that doesn't matter. The js-file is transferred to the client and then the client is able to modify every part of it before he sends his requests. He can change the key to whatever he wants. That is why I hope you could specify the use cases of your script in general. Are there security issues you want to manage? If so, why? Or what else?

Comment: @TRD i just don't want people to flood the system, or just use the api with it if they are not from the website.

Comment: Well, preventing the people from flooding the system can be achieved by setting a timestamp within the php session and then check the difference between now and that timestamp to be larger than a defined duration. I misunderstood your approach with the api key. I thought this shall be a kind of key in which case his "public" visibility is not what a key would be supposed for. The context you mean is more like a token. You generate a token (your so called api key) which is generated by the system and is not predictable. This key is stored in session and checked to ensure access from your site.

Answer (score 1):

Your objective seems to be to protect your server API from being hit/spammed by unauthorised/excessive requests. In this circumstance where everything that you're looking to inspect can be spoofed, you may want to try using a proof of work algorithm instead.

Have a look at http://hashcash.org

By forcing a client to "pay" (with compute cycles) for sending you data to be processed, you can filter out general bots from causing you a problem.